# How can i inject an object inside a context of a draggable element in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, draggable, droppable

I use draggable/droppable JQuery feature as follows

```
div.container {
    height:400px;
}

<div class="container" id="source">
    <div id="0">Item 0</div>
    <div id="1">Item 1</div>
    <div id="2">Item 2</div>
</div>

<div class="container" id="target"></div>

$("#source div").draggable({
    helper:"clone",
        revert:"invalid"
    });
```

I would like to know whether is possible inject an object inside a context of a draggable object. Something like

```
var contextualObject = {"property":"value"};

$("#source div").draggable({
    helper:"clone",
        revert:"invalid",
        injected:contextualObject
    });
```

So in target container i could use something like (Notice second alert statement)

```
$("#target").droppable({
    accept:"#source div",
tolerance: "fit",
drop:function(e, ui) {
        alert("You have dropped id " + $(this).attr("id"));

        alert("Its contextual value is: " + $(this).draggable("option", "injected.property"));
}});
```

How can i do it ?

regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery data](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/data) is made for this sort of thing.

```
$("#source div").draggable({
    helper:"clone",
        revert:"invalid",
        start: function(evt,ui) {
           $(this).data('injected', contextualObject)
        }
    });
```

Then, in your droppable:

```
 var obj = $(ui.draggable).data('injected');
 console.log(obj.property);
```

A couple of notes:

- You should use `ui.draggable` in your drop to get the item that is drag and dropped. `this` is the item getting dropped on
- Element id's should start [with a letter](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name), not a number.

I have a working demo [here](http://jsbin.com/ikide).

Comment: Have you try it ? It does not appear to work. In droppable it complains obj is undefined.

Comment: I didn't try it but I have now and fixed the bug in it.  You should use `ui.draggable` for the element that is being dragged.  this is the droppable element. Sorry about that.